# swift - check if uitextfield in another class is empty

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, option-type

I want to validate a form that is in a container in a parent view controller. How can I validate the form (check that all fields are not `nil`) when a button in the parent view controller is clicked. The button has an `IBOutlet` in the parent view controller that calls a method from the form's class.

```
    @IBAction func submitOrder(sender: AnyObject) {
        let formView = FormViewController()
        formView.getFieldValues()
    }
```

The method is,

```
    func getFieldValues() {
        if (self.nameField.text == "") {
            print("Name field is empty")
        }
    }
```

The `nameField` in the child view has the IBOutlet,

```
@IBOutlet weak var nameField: UITextField!
```

When the button in the parent view controller is clicked I get the classic error,

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

So this has something to do with optionals or the parent view controller not recognizing the text fields in the container view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lou is correct about the root of the problem being the new, unconnected instance of `FormViewController`. To get the parent view controller to recognize the `uiTextFields` of the container view, you have to use `prepareForSegue`. After naming the `containerView` segue in the storyboard, you have to implement this method.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "formView" {
        formView = segue.destinationViewController as? FormViewController
    }
}
```

`formView` is the empty instance of FormViewController declared within the class. Making this connection allows the parent view class to get the values of the `UITextFields` in `FormViewController`

Answer (score 2):

When you wrote:

```
    let formView = FormViewController()
    formView.getFieldValues()
```

You created a brand new FormViewController that was not loaded from a Storyboard and therefore does not have outlets hooked up.  But, even if they were hooked up to something, it would be to new text fields, not the ones on the screen.

You are not supposed to create a new one -- you are supposed to access the one that you are showing.

Without more code, we can't help, but where ever in the parent you created the form view that is showing, keep a reference to it so you can access it later.

Comment: The child view in the container view is a subclass of UITableView since it has static cells. How can i make an instance of FormViewController that connects to the container view which is a UIView?

Comment: Pretty sure you can find it in the parent's childViewControllers -- probably has just one object -- you can cast to see if it's in.

Answer (score 0):

One way is that you can save the textfield data (whatever user typed) temporarily (like in user defaults) using textfield's delegate methods.

When button is clicked you just need to check that stored data and if nothing is typed then it return nil or empty string whatever it is you can identify that and validate textfield.